# Export symbology when exporting features in QGIS 3.4.5 using Python script?

Tags: python, qgis-3, symbology

Here is the code that I have used .. but the symbology export does not work.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    layer.selectByExpression('"col_name"= {}.format(i))
    selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(ponds, 'filepath.kml', "utf-8", layer.crs(), "KML", onlySelected=True,symbologyExport=2 )
```

`SymbologyExport` is not working.

I have also tried `symbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbolLayerSymbology`
and `symbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology`, but none of them seem to work.

Any idea how to export symbology when exporting features using Python?

Comment: Hi, i have the same question, some one can tell me please how can I define the symbology when export to KML file with pyqgis?